# Visual Basics - Solution doesn't load

Tags: visual-studio

My institution has been using Visual Studio 2017 for Visual Basic. I recently  bought a new laptop and downloaded and installed VS 2019. When I load the project file it says `"one or more solutions cannot be loaded".` 
I'm very confused on how to make my VB 2017 file work on VB 2019.

If you could help that would be great!
Thanks In advance

Comment: Right click on your project and select 'Reload project' and then check the outlog log why it cannot be loaded.

Comment: Chances are you didn't copy all of the project files.